# How can I install AMD Graphic Drivers on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, software-installation, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

I had always been a Windows user, Three days ago, I decided to start working with Linux Ubuntu 18.04. I had read in forums that they recommend it to new users.I downloaded it and installed it.

I search AMD drivers for ubuntu 18.04 [Here](https://www.amd.com/en/support), but i find my AMD drivers only for old version on ubuntu.

Can you help and learn me how to install AMD graphics driver on ubuntu 18.04 step by step please. Thank you !!

**lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'**

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 [8086:5916] (rev 02)
01:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445] [1002:6900] (rev c3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your AMD graphics should support 2D and 3D acceleration out-of-the-box. There isn't a compelling reason to use the drivers offered at [amd.com](https://www.amd.com/en/support); the open-source driver is the foundation of the closed-source drivers, and the open-source driver outperforms the "pro" drivers in many cases.

To understand AMD's strategy regarding its display drivers, [Phoronix](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=search&q=AMDGPU) is an excellent place to start. If you want to use the most recent drivers, two [PPA](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PPA)'s offer zero-configuration installation:

- [Oibaf](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers) The more conservative choice.
- [Padoka](https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/pkppa) Less stable, but more current.

Both include easy instructions to install, and revert to stock if things don't work out. However, I've been using `oibaf` trouble free for some time.

Summary: AMD's best display drivers are open source and included with recent Ubuntu releases, more current versions are available via PPA.

Comment: I make this step 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt upgrade

And get this erorr:
Read package lists ... Done
Build a tree with dependencies
Reading the status information ... Done
Calculate the update ... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that,
that you required an impossible situation or if you were using the unstable one
distributing that some necessary packages are not yet created or not
have been moved from Inbox.
The following information can help you find a way out of the situation:

Comment: The following packages have unsatisfied dependencies:
  libwayland-egl1-mesa: In conflict with libwayland-egl1
E: Broken packets
 What i need to do in this case

Comment: It's hard to say exactly what's wrong, but this looks like you had previously attempted to install packages. The complaint is that you have a package which is described as conflicting with a package that you are trying to install from the `oibaf` PPA. The cleanest way to fix would be to remove the package that caused the conflicting package to be installed. Did you attempt to install the `deb` from amd.com, perhaps?

Comment: Btw, I had exactly this problem months ago. This thread describes the source of the problem: https://www.phoronix.com/forums/forum/linux-graphics-x-org-drivers/opengl-vulkan-mesa-gallium3d/24959-updated-and-optimized-ubuntu-free-graphics-drivers/page181 This is why I suspect that you have an older package installed from a previous attempt.

Comment: I add padoka ppa , but can you tell me how to switch to my AMD card, becouse in my addiction driver is empty аnd I dont know how to make the drivers see themselves there.

<pre>sudo lshw -C video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
</pre>
*-display
       description: Display controller
       product: Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]

Comment: Sure... There many questions and more answers to this second question. I'll answer here real quick, but you may wish to edit your original question with an update about switching. The quickest and dirtiest way is to use the `DRI_PRIME=1` approach, which will use the AMD GPU on a per-application basis (there are many questions on this StackExchange). To test, try this in a terminal: `DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"`.